# Performance of the MPI_win_lock

Tags: mpi

I face a big challenge to justify the performance of the following snapshot of my code that uses Intel MPI library

```
double time=0
time = time - MPI_Wtime();
MPI_Win_lock(MPI_LOCK_EXCLUSIVE,0,0,win_global_scheduling_step); 
MPI_Win_unlock(0,win_global_scheduling_step);
time= time + MPI_Wtime();
if(id==0)
   sleep(10);
printf("%d sync time %f\n", id, time);
```

The output depends on how much will rank 0 sleep.

As the following

0 sync time 0.000305

1 sync time 10.00045

2 sync time 10.00015

If I change the sleep of the rank 0 to be 5 seconds instead of 10 seconds, then the sync time at the other ranks will be of the same scale of 5 seconds

The actual data associated with the window "win_global_step" is owned by rank 0

Any discussion or thoughts about the code would be so helpful

Comment: please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: ... and describe your setup properly.

Comment: Did you have a barrier before your first mpi_wtime? They need to be aligned to ensure they *start* at the same time, otherwise you may see the effect of prior balancing issues?

Answer (score 1):

If rank 0 owns the win_global_step, and rank 0 goes to sleep or cranks away on a computation kernel, or otherwise does not make MPI calls, many MPI implementations will not be able to service other requests.

There is an environment variable (`MPICH_ASYNC_PROGRESS`) you might try setting.  It introduces some big performance tradeoffs, but it can in some instances let RMA operations make progress without explicit calls to MPI routines.

Despite the name "MPICH" in the environment variable, it might work for you as Intel MPI is based off of the MPICH implementation.